# How to get back ip address on Mac

Tags: mac

I used these commands and I no longer have an IP address. I have googled but can't find a solution to get an IP address back.

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

I used those commands because I wanted to change an IP address.

I am using Macbook Pro Retina 2012, OS X Version 10.8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To release and renew your IP address in Mac OS X, you’ll use the Network system preferences to renew the DHCP Lease.

1. Click the Apple button and choose System Preferences.
2. Click the Network icon in the Internet and Network section.
3. Select your method of connecting to the internet. (Ethernet or Wi-Fi)
4. Click Advanced.
5. If you selected Ethernet, you should already be in the TCP/IP tab heading. If you aren’t, or if you selected Wi-Fi, click the TCP/IP tab heading.
6. Click Renew DHCP Lease.
7. Click OK to exit the Advanced window, and then exit System Preferences. A restart may be required to complete the process.

**Terminal**

To **release** your IP address:

1. Enter the Terminal from the root account.
2. Type `ifconfig ethX down` (X is the Ethernet adapter you are looking to release, usually eth0).
3. Press Enter.

TO **RENEW** YOUR IP ADDRESS:

5. While still in the Terminal from the root account, type `ifconfig ethX up` (again, where X is the Ethernet adapter you are
   looking to renew, usually eth0).
6. Press Enter

If this doesn't work then you can try restarting your router and MAC.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: It's not providing new IP Still getting same IP again and Again multiple restart

Comment: @Shankar what is your OS X version?

Comment: OS version is - Catalina